# Is NClone thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, nclone

I would like to use NClone in a multithreaded application.

```
 Clone.ObjectGraph(myObject)
```

NClone's ObjectGraph is a static method. Supposing I guard my objects (so no other threads can access to those objects during the clone operation), is the Clone.ObjectGraph itself thread safe (again when cloning only *different* objects at the same time), or should I guard the Clone.ObjectGraph(...) operation itself to prevent reentrance? (sounds as a terrible bottleneck)

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze source code of NClone: https://github.com/mijay/NClone

As I see `Clone.ObjectGraph` is thread-safe becase it creates own `ReplicationContext` [for every call](https://github.com/mijay/NClone/blob/74a71b13d1f129492daaefbb2f582eaf187eac74/src/NClone/ObjectReplication/ObjectReplicator.cs#L52):

```
public T Replicate<T>(T source)
{
    return new ReplicationContext(replicationStrategyFactory).Replicate(source).As<T>();
}
```